# Should I keep showing the post's image and title to the user through the scenes?

Tags: mobile

Do I have to keep showing the information my user has already inputted (I have seen a few big apps that do this)? If so I would have to redesign my scene, so is it really important or is it good as is?

I would love any kind of advice, design or ux related, but just answering is more than enough (:

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "scenes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to keep a small visual reminder of the post on each scene, as it's less costly cognitively speaking than recalling it (working memory is very limited in number of assets and duration).

If you have a review of the entire process with all information in the final scene, it can compensate for the absence in the intermediate screens.

However, if users are interrupted in the middle of the process, it's likely that they will need to check what they were doing when they come back. If they can easily navigate back to the 1st screen without losing the information they already entered, it could work, but it's not ideal, as any additional step is a chance for the user to give up and leave.

Comment: That makes sense! What do you think a good 'small visual reminder' would be between the scenes I posted? I thought of putting the image and title at the top of the fourth step but that looks horrible...

Thanks

Comment: The title and a miniature image would be best.

Comment: I edited my post with that scene with a miniature image and the title, what do you think? Maybe that's too small and just would make for a worse experience for the user? Also added another possibility, which I honestly do not like a lot, but either way I would value your opinion about both. Thanks.

Comment: You need to decide that by yourself or do some testing. The goal of UXStackExchange is not to do a review of specific designs, but to be a library of solved UX issues reusable by anyone.